# aws Glue: Is it possible to pull only specific data from a database?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I need to transform a fairly big database table with aws Glue to csv. However I only the newest table rows from the past 24 hours. There ist a column which specifies the creation date of the row. Is it possible, to just transform these rows, without copying the whole table into the csv file? I am using a python script with Spark.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are some Built-in Transforms in AWS Glue which are used to process your data. This transfers can be called from ETL scripts.

Please refer the below link for the same :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/built-in-transforms.html

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the type of `database` that you are trying connect. Anyway for `JDBC` connections spark has the option of [**query**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), in which you can issue the usual `SQL query` to get the *rows* you need.